# Separate original email from the replies with Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, extract, body-parser

Does anyone of you have an idea about how could I separate the original email from the replies? I would like to get every body of the email from the conversation without the name of the sender nor the other details. I tried this code, It works well but it only returns the body of the recent email. I could not get the body of the replies.

Here is an example:

```
--Original email-- 
Dear Chadha,

I hope that you are doing well.

Best Regards, 
Date:..... 
Email:..... 
--reply-- 
From:.... 
to:..... 
Dear Yesmine, 
Thank you for asking, 
I am doing well. 
Kindest Regards, 
Date:...
```

My question is I would like to separate the first original email from the reply and get the body of both of them. The code that I used gave me only the body of the first email without the replies. I am looking for a solution for that. I think that Regex would help me in this case but I don t know how.

```py
def extractBody(emailString):
    salutes = ["dear"] # A list containing greetings key words, like 'dear', 'hi', etc
    goodbyes = ["best regards"] # A list containing email footers like 'best regards' 'bye', etc

    # Split your email by line breaks and make everything lowercase
    emailLines = emailString.lower().split("\n")
    normalLines = emailString.split("\n") 

    # Start and end points to extract the text
    start = -1
    end = len(emailLines) - 1

    for i in range(len(emailLines)):
        line  = emailLines[i]

        # Check if any salute words in this line
        if len([s for s in salutes if s in line]) and start == -1:
            start = i + 1
            continue

        # Check if any goodbyes in this line
        if len([s for s in goodbyes if s in line]) and end == len(emailLines) - 1:
            end = i
            break

    if start == -1:
        return "\n".join(normalLines[:end])
    else:
        return "\n".join(normalLines[start:end])

extract =  extractBody(body).strip()
print(f"{extract}")
```

Comment: That would be difficult to answer without any example data and the expected outcome.

Comment: Yeah you re right, I tried to add an example of an original email containing some replies, I would like to separate every message and get the body

Comment: I added a text example

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting but I had to guess some things; please review.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :D